# Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Virtual Machine download link not working

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have been trying to download the `MS Edge on Win 10` virtual machine from the `dev.modern.ie` website and I'm getting the same message in all the browsers:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My windows firewall is deactivated and I'm not using a proxy for my LAN, I have also tried cleaning all my browsing data but still getting the same error.

I really need to test a website i'm working with in Edge, is there a mirror or another link to download the virtual machines?

Comment: its working for me - can you elaborate on the settings for the file you are using, and the browser you are using

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce the issue you're reporting when I initiated Microsoft Edge downloads for HyperV 2012, VirtualBox, and VMWare. This may have been a temporary issue that has since been resolved — please try again and let us know if the problem persists.

You can also test EdgeHTML (the rendering engine behind Microsoft Edge) by streaming RemoteIE to your Mac, PC, or Android/iOS device. While the shell of the browser will be Internet Explorer, the actual *internals* will be EdgeHTML: https://remote.modern.ie.

If you encounter further issues, please do not hesitate to remote them directly to me either here on Stack Overflow, or via Twitter.